# Referencing observableArray object property from view.

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've a problem with `Knockout.JS` when I try to set the visibility of a button depending on an specific object property from a `observableArray`. The object *binded* to my view is this one:

```
function IncomeDeclarationHub() {
        var self = this;
        //Other properties
        self.IncomeDeclarationViewModel = ko.observableArray();
 }
```

And of course this is the object used to fill that `observableArray`:

```
function IncomeDeclarationViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        //Other properties
        self.IsSent = ko.observable(data.IsSent);
}
```

At some point I fill `IncomeDeclarationViewModel` with data, and it works fine. The thing is that I need to show a button only if the property `IsSent` from the first element of said `observableArray` is true. So I tried many things like:

```
<input type="image" data-bind="visible: IncomeDeclarationViewModel()[0].IsSent()" />
```

Also changing where I make the reference for `visible: IncomeDeclarationViewModel[0].IsSent()` or `visible: IncomeDeclarationViewModel()[0].IsSent`.

But I keep getting this **error**:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'IsSent' of undefined;
Bindings value: click: Print, visible: myIncomeDeclarationViewModel()[0].IsSent()
```

**What I'm missing or where I'm wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because at some point IncomeDeclarationViewModel isn't populated which causes the error as there will be no object in the first element if the array is empty.

Change the binding to this to check if there are elements in the array:

```
<input type="image" data-bind="visible: IncomeDeclarationViewModel().length > 0 && IncomeDeclarationViewModel()[0].IsSent()" />
```

An alternative to this is to use the [with](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) binding which any children bindings will only display and execute if there is an object in the first item of IncomeDeclarationViewModel:

```
<div data-bind="with: IncomeDeclarationViewModel()[0]">
    <input type="image" data-bind="visible: IsSent" />
</div>
```

Comment: You are right, the thing is at first the observableArray is empty so that property don't exists. The alternative works just fine.